# Is a virtual desktop also a virtual machine?

Tags: virtualization

Generally is a virtual desktop also a virtual machine? Or is it normal/possible to have multiple virtual desktops on one virtual machine?

UPDATE:
I know what a Virtual Machine is, I also know the difference between a virtual desktop and a VDI.

If I were to rephrase my question, I would ask, is there a one to one Or one to many relation between a Virtual machine and a Virtual desktop. (It would be one to many, if multiple virtual desktops are installed on one VM. And that individual customizations are handled by having separate data files, like in SaaS, where multiple users use one app but their customizations are stored in separate data files)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_desktop - "In computing, a virtual desktop is a term used with respect to user interfaces, usually within the WIMP paradigm, to describe ways in which the virtual space of a computer's desktop environment is expanded beyond the physical limits of the screen's display area through the use of software. This compensates for a limited desktop area and can also be helpful in reducing clutter."

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_virtualization#Virtual_desktop_infrastructure - "Virtual Desktop Infrastructure (VDI) is a desktop-centric service that hosts user desktop environments on remote servers and/or blade PCs, which are accessed over a network using a remote display protocol. A connection brokering service is used to connect users to their assigned desktop sessions. For users, this means they can access their desktop from any location, without being tied to a single client device."

Comment: Do you mean a Virtual Desktop, or VDI?  What in the standard definitions are you having trouble with?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine - "A virtual machine (VM) is a software implementation of a machine (i.e. a computer) that executes programs like a physical machine."

Comment: Again, are you talking about Virtual Desktops (first link) or VDI, (second link)?  You keep saying Virtual Desktops which, by the primary definition, have nothing to do with the machine they're on, virtual or otherwise.  VDI on the other-hand, usually spins up a VM to provide the desktop environment for the user, but not always.  What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase the question to only ask the part that you're interested in. Explain what you do know and exactly where you need some clarification. That way, someone will be able to help you :)